# Check logged user with normal and ajax request

Tags: spring-mvc

I use interceptor to check if a user is logged in every controller call like this :

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {

    if(request.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("redirect:/login?next="+
             URLEncoder.encode(
                   request.getRequestURL().toString() + "" +
                   (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "")
            ,"utf-8");

        return false;
    }   

    return true;
}
```

It work fine for normal request but for ajax request i can't make a `response.sendRedirect(..)`.

1. How to know if it's a ajax or normal request ?
2. How can i do it like if i got a ajax error ?

   ```
   $.ajax({ 
      .....
      success : function(data) { ...... },     
      error   : function(){ 
             alert("login error"); // or 
             document.location = '/path/login' // or something else
      }

   });
   ```
3. There a other way to handle it rather than using interceptor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1. How to know if it's a ajax or normal request ?*

You can check inside your interceptor for the existence of the `X-Requested-With` header. This header is always added to the ajax request by the jQuery library (to my knowing almost all major js libraries add it as well) with the purpose of preventing the [Cross-Site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). To figure out if the request is ajax, you can write your `preHandle` method like

```
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        String requestedWith = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
        Boolean isAjax = requestedWith != null ? "XMLHttpRequest".equals(requestedWith) : false;
...
}
```

*2. How can i do it like if i got a ajax error ?*

As you've already noticed, ajax request don't recognize server side redirects, as the intention of the server side redirects is to be transparent to the client. In the case of an ajax request, don't do redirect rather set some status code to the response e.g. `response.setStatus(respCode)` or add a custom header e.g. `response.setHeader("Location", "/path/login")`, and read it through in the jQuery's [complete](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method which is a callback that follows after either `success` or `error`, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    //...        
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
        // do something e.g. redirect
    } 
});
```

*3. There a other way to handle it rather than using interceptor ?*

Definitely. Checkout [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). Its a framework, and adds a bit to the learning curve, but its well worth it. It will add much more than a custom solution, e.g. you'll get authorization mechanism on top of the authentication. When your application matures, you'll notice that the straigthforward implementation that you're on to now, has quite a few security flaws that are not hard to exploit e.g. [session fixation](https://blog.frankel.ch/session-fixation-and-how-to-fix-it), where spring security can easily protect you. There's plenty of examples online, and you'll get better support here on the SO in comparison to any custom solution. You can unit test it, an asset I personally value very much

Comment: I try it without `WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter` and it works just with `"XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"))` ... and does every ajax call (jquery, native or other framwork) contain `X-Requested-With` header ?

Comment: good point, I copied from my production code where I wrap the request for totally different reasons. The header is added by jQuery, I've explained a bit more in the edited answer about that part as well

Answer (score 1):

You could simply:

- Refuse ajax requests before the user is properly logged in
- once the user logs in, set a security token in the session or somewhere
- pass that token in the ajax request and use that token to validate on the server side prehandle
- in your case you would check the existence of the token before running into the code

Also, the preHandle does not have to apply to every routes, you could also have different routes each with different authorisation, prehandle, code.